# Multiple Enums with same case

Tags: swift, enums

Is there a better approach to tackle this situation.

I am following MVVM for my project and we have `ViewModels` for every `ViewController`, which feed them the required data. The data is passed back through `enums` with associatedValues.

Suppose, we have

```
enum HomeViewModelState {
    case failure(String)
    case anotherState(SomeModel)
}

enum ListingViewModelState {
    case failure(String)
    case anotherState(SomeModel)
}
```

As we see we have a repetitive case i.e. `failure(String)` that pass back the error message incase of an api failure. I want to avoid this repetitive task. Is there a better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create one state enum that uses generics:

```
enum ViewModelState<T> {
    case failure(String)
    case anotherState(T)
}
```

Comment: Yes I am marking this as right, because I did used it earlier, but eventually I am not using this now. The reason is that the handling of cases becomes more complex by using this. By using this, in view models you now have to pass completions as (ViewModelState<HomeViewModelState>) -> Void and similarly you have to now handle the state in View Controllers either by nested switches or multiple functions inside a function like func handleState(state: (ViewModelState<HomeViewModelState>) -> Void) making it look less cleaner.

Comment: Aside: You can use a typealias to clean up your code if you want: `typealias HomeViewModel = ViewModelState<HomeViewModelState>`, or even `typealias HomeViewModelFunction = (ViewModelState<HomeViewModelState>) -> Void`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) instead of multiple enums, you will have a state stored as `Result<SomeModel, Error>` in every controller (and each controller can have a different model. The state assignment is convenient, you are no longer passing strings as errors, and will use proper `Error` protocol instead:

```
var state: Result<SomeModel1, Error>
...
state = .failure(MyCustomErrors.badThingHappened)
state = .success(SomeModel)

enum MyCustomErrors: Error {
    case badThingHappened
```

It's still an `enum` and can be used in a `switch` statement:

```
switch state {
case .success(let model):
   ...
case .failure(let error):
   ...
}
```